# join() method is not working properly in my implemented code

Tags: java, multithreading

Problem - Create N threads (e.g. 3, names can be Thread-1, Thread-2, Thread-3), which will say HelloWorld in reverse order i.e. First Thread-3 will say HelloWorld, then Thread-2 then Thread-1.

Solution - Above problem can be solved in various ways like using a volatile flag to indicate which thread has to run or using join method (so that Thread-1 completion depends upon Thread-2 and Thread-2's on Thread-3).
I am trying to solve this by join method. But it is not giving me proper result. Please help me. Below is my program -

```
Thread [] previosThread = {null};
    int[] previousIndex = {0};
    for (int i=3; i>=1; i--) {
        int currentIndex = i;
        System.out.print("PreviousIndex--"+previousIndex[0]+"  ;  ");
        System.out.println("CurrentIndex--"+currentIndex);
        Thread newThread = new Thread("Thread-"+i) {
            public void run() {
                if(previousIndex[0]!=0 && previousIndex[0]==currentIndex+1) {
                    try {
                        previosThread[0].join();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(this.getName()+" is saying HelloWorld!!");
            }
        };
        previosThread[0] = newThread;
        previousIndex[0] = currentIndex;
        newThread.start();
    }
```

Above program is giving uncertain output like below -

> PreviousIndex--0  ;  CurrentIndex--3
>   PreviousIndex--3  ;  CurrentIndex--2
>   PreviousIndex--2  ;  CurrentIndex--1
>   Thread-2 is saying HelloWorld!!
>   Thread-1 is saying HelloWorld!!
>   Thread-3 is saying HelloWorld!!

Comment: Starting a thread takes a small amount of time. Your loop will very likely complete before *any* thread actually enters the `run()` method, so `previosThread[0]` references the *last* thread. All 3 threads will see that last value.

Comment: @Andreas : Many Thanks. You solved my problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

According to Andreas' comment, I was using previosThread[0] incorrectly. Rather than using previosThread[0], I have maintained a separate array of created threads so that I can call join method correctly on the new thread and then started each threads of this array in reverse order as to work the join method properly, both caller and dependent thread should running. Below is my code ---

```
public class AntThread extends Thread {

private Thread dependentThread;
private String threadName;
private int index;
public AntThread(Thread dependentThread, String threadName, int index) {
    super(threadName);
    this.dependentThread = dependentThread;
    this.threadName = threadName;
    this.index = index;
}

public void run() {
    if(dependentThread!=null) {
        try {
            dependentThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            this.interrupt();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" is saying - HelloWorld");
}
```

}

and the main class --

public class MultipleThreadsGreetingInReverseOrderTest {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    int size = 10;
    Thread [] createdThreads = new Thread[size];
    for(int i=size; i>0; i--) {
        Thread dependentThread = null;
        if(i!=size)
            dependentThread = createdThreads[i];
        Thread antThread = new AntThread(dependentThread, "Thread-"+i, i);
        createdThreads[i-1] = antThread;
    }

    //Starting the last thread first, as the join condition will work only when dependent thread is runnning
    for(int j=createdThreads.length-1; j>=0; j--) {
        createdThreads[j].start();
    }

}
```

}

Many Thanks Andreas!! for the quick response.